# Obtener los comentarios asociados a un post

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Estoy haciendo una Api con laravel, y quería hacer una ruta: posts/comments
donde esta mostrara todos los posts con sus respectivos comentarios en formato json,
pero al momento de mostrar los posts quería que hubiera como un nuevo campo donde ahí se mostrar los comentarios, algo así:

```
"Posts": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "user_id": 7,
  "titulo": "Dr.",
  "contenido": "Adipisci sequi nam distinctio inventore magnam rerum fuga.",
  "created_at": "2020-10-17 17:16:49",
  "updated_at": "2020-10-17 17:16:49"
  "Comentarios": "Aqui se muestran todos los comentarios del post"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "user_id": 2,
  "titulo": "Dr.",
  "contenido": "Quia dicta sunt mollitia eos tenetur.",
  "created_at": "2020-10-17 17:16:49",
  "updated_at": "2020-10-17 17:16:49"
  "Comentarios": "Aqui se muestran todos los comentarios del post"
},
```

Mi pregunta es, como le puedo hacer para que me muestre los posts con sus respectivos comentarios como el ejemplo anterior?

api.php

```
Route::get('posts/comments', 'PostController@posts_comments');
```

PostController.php

```
    public function posts_comments(){

    return response()->json([
        "Posts" => DB::table('posts')->get(),
        "Comments" => DB::table('comments')->get(), //solo muestra la tabla, no hay relacion con un post
    ],200);
}
```

Modelo Post.php

```
class Post extends Model
{

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function comment(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
}
```

Modelo Comment.php

```
class Comment extends Model
{
public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
}
```

Comment: ¿Ya definiste la relación en el modelo `Comment`?

Comment: Si, ya actualiza la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observaciones:

- La forma en que procesas la consulta no es la correcta y tienes al momento 2 opciones:

  - Continúas invocando a las entidades por medio del facade `DB` y su método `table` para constituir un `join`
  - O bien puedes (*ya que parece las tienes definidas*) ocupar las relaciones de Eloquent, (*importante aclarar esto **no** es un join*)

Lo anterior te lo comento por que estás haciendo 2 consultas aisladas que te retornarán información pero no tienen bajo este criterio que usas el por que mostrar la información con la estructura que tu deseas (*es decir ahí únicamente tienes 2 `SELECTS` independientes uno del otro*).

Una vez aclarados los puntos anteriores, en el modelo comment declara la inversa de la relación que sería: `belongsTo()` así (*en algún momento la vas a terminar ocupando*):

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Hecho lo anterior, ahora si podemos indicar una consulta que devuelva la información solicitada de esta forma:

```
Post::with('comments')->get();
```

Lo anterior te retornará 2 colecciones:

- La colección de posts
- Por cada post una colección con todos sus comments asociados

**Referencias**

- [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Ya el resto te lo dejo a ti....

Comment: Okey, gracias por tus observaciones me ayudan bastante, y muchas gracias por tu respuesta te agradezco.